# Access Method of another Addon

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

I want to automate a Dashboard based on Google Analytics Data. This Addon https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on  is Fetching the data for me. I was wondering if there was any way I could call methods in the addon.

I know that I can access the Google Analytics data by using the API, but i would rather not do so.

I would like to know how to call the method responsible for fetching the data.
As an alternative the sourcecode of the Addon would be great as well, but as far as I know there is no way to access the source.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right from the beginning of Google Apps Script, developers wanted a way to publish apps without openly publishing the code.

Finally, add-ons have provided a way to do that. The [announcement of Add-ons](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.ca/2014/03/add-ons.html) made this clear.

> - **Share functionality without sharing code:** Unlike regular Apps Script projects, add-ons don't expose your source code for all to see. That's reassuring both to less-technical users and to the keepers of your 
>     codebase's secrets.

The fact that you cannot see the source or call functions is by design. Unless the author of the code chooses to make it open-source, you're on your own.